# kubectl invalid apiVersion

Tags: kubectl

This may be an obvious mistake, but it took me a while to figure out (as I'm new to kubernetes), so I'm posting it here to ease the life of others.

Was getting the following error:

```
D:\>kubectl get pods
error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

The kubectl version was:

```
D:\>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.11", 
GitCommit:"637c7e288581ee40ab4ca210618a89a555b6e7e9", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11- 
26T14:38:32Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1"
```

My kube config file contained:

```
exec:
  apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

I tried changing apiVersion to v1alpha1, v1,etc.  None of that helped with different errors along the way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1" CircleCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72126048/error-exec-plugin-invalid-apiversion-client-authentication-k8s-io-v1alpha1-c)

Comment: @Dorian Thanks, that was it for me on an Amazon Linux instance with v1 CLI preinstalled.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue was with kubectl version, and in particular with docker desktop installed on the system.  When I finally explicitly downloaded version 1.16 but kubectl was still reporting 1.10, it was easy to spot the problem.  I moved PATH variable pointing to my kubectl.exe to the front (top) of the PATH, tried in a new CMD window and kubectl worked fine.

Btw, this issue with kubectl being picked up from docker desktop install is noted on the [kubectl download site](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/#install-kubectl-on-windows), I just never noticed it.

Comment: I followed the link and didn't find ref to Docker Desktop any more.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OSX, the issue can be fixed by doing the following:

```
curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.23.6/bin/darwin/amd64/kubectl

chmod +x ./kubectl

sudo mv ./kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
```

Comment: That's just installing a fixed (new) version of kubectl. This'll actually cause *more* apiVersion errors, most likely