# Terraform failed to destroy with kubernetes autoscaler

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, gitlab-ci, amazon-eks

I have been using following snippet to manage kubernetes auto scaling with terraform

```
resource "helm_release" "cluster-autoscaler" {
  depends_on = [
    module.eks
  ]

  name             = "cluster-autoscaler"
  namespace        = local.k8s_service_account_namespace
  repository       = "https://kubernetes.github.io/autoscaler"
  chart            = "cluster-autoscaler"
  version          = "9.10.7"
  create_namespace = false
```

While all of this has been in working state for months (Gitlab CI/CD), it has suddenly stopped working and throwing following error.

```
module.review_vpc.helm_release.cluster-autoscaler: Refreshing state... [id=cluster-autoscaler]
╷
│ Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: exec plugin: invalid apiVersion "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
│
│   with module.review_vpc.helm_release.cluster-autoscaler,
│   on ..\..\modules\aws\eks.tf line 319, in resource "helm_release" "cluster-autoscaler":
│  319: resource "helm_release" "cluster-autoscaler" {
```

I am using AWS EKS with kubernetes version 1.21.

The terraform providers are as follows

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
    kubectl = {
      source  = "gavinbunney/kubectl"
      version = "1.14.0"
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here is the module for eks

```
module "eks" {
  source                       = "terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws"
  version                      = "17.24.0"
```

Comment: Are you using your own EKS module or one of the publically available?

Comment: @MarkoE updated question with EKS module details.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72327670/5607207

Comment: @SYN Please check my question, so option 1 is not applicable. Option 2 fails with different error.

Comment: ... What's the new error after fixing kubeconfig apiversion? Can you reproduce outside of terraform?

Comment: This is an awscli bug. I resolved recently by upgrading awscli: https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/6920

Comment: Got the same issue and I replaced the kubectl from AWS to make it work: https://s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazon-eks/1.21.2/2021-07-05/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl

Answer (score 1):

I had to do couple of changes to terraform scripts (not sure whey they were not required earlier).

- Added helm to required_providers section

  helm = {
  source  = "hashicorp/helm"
  version = "2.3.0"
  }
- Replaced token generation from

  exec {
  api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
  args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--cluster-name", var.eks_cluster_name]
  command     = "aws"
  }

to

```
token = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
```

Note that I am using `hashicorp/terraform:1.0.11` image on Gitlab runner to execute Terraform Code. Hence manually installing kubectl or aws CLI is not applicable in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Helm v3.9 version issue.

Check which version you are using, if so, just do the downgrade to v3.8.

---

Don't forget to confirm that you are also using the version of kubectl v1.21 and aws-cli v2.7

Comment: Appreciate your input and thanks for your time. I have posted my solution.